# Why is my array resolved to an int yet I declared it as an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I've been trying to code a program that calculates the verification number of a serial number according to a certain formula(in the for loop).

The serial number begins with a letter of the alphabet with must be converted to a number according to it's position in the alphabet(e.g: A=1, Z=26.

In order to do this I figured I would need to use arrays and/or chars, however I'm only getting to know the two and don't know how to proceed.

**In line 13 I get the error** `The type of expression must be an array but is resolved to an int`. Why am I getting this error? What do I need to change? I've tried to figure it out on my own and have read tons of other posts here on the topic but i just can't seem to figure it out. Please, please help me..

I'm pretty sure the code could be cleaned up as well since I'm very new to programming and just figuring out code conventions and all, so I'd really appreciate any suggestions on what I could change to improve my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Pruefziffer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Geben Sie die Seriennummer ein");
          int serienNummer = scanner.nextInt();

            int[] landkennung = serienNummer[0] - 'A' + 1;
            int quersumme = (landkennung % 10) + (landkennung / 10);
            int pruefziffer = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                quersumme += serienNummer[i] - '0';

            }

            pruefziffer = 8 - quersumme % 9;

            if (pruefziffer == 0) {
                 pruefziffer = 9;
           }         
    System.out.println(pruefziffer);     
}
}
```

Comment: whats this `quersumme += serienNummer[i] - '0';`

Comment: ` int[] landkennung = serienNummer[0] - 'A' + 1;` you have declared an array but you assign a value of an integer

Comment: `serienNummer` is an `int`, but you try to access it via array subscription `serienNummer[0]`. Also: `Scanner.nextInt()` won't work as your serial number is supposed to start with a letter (`char`), not an `int`.

Comment: I think you first read how to declare an array and how to traverse through an array ?

Comment: Yeah I thought just as much, how can I change the scanner to read a letter and the numbers that follow it?

Answer (score 0):

```
  int serienNummer = scanner.nextInt();
  int[] landkennung = serienNummer[0] - 'A' + 1;
```

you've declared `serienNummer` as an `int` and you're trying to use it as an array`serienNummer[0]`and `landkennung` is an array reference and your assigning it a single value.

Comment: How can I correct this? 
do I even need the array?
assigning it single value?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the line int[] landkennung = serienNummer[0] - 'A' + 1;

You declare landkennung as an int[], but attempt to assign it the value of an int.

Another issue is that serienNummer is an int, but you attempt to access it as though it were an array.

Also landkennung / 10 would only work if landkennung was something other than an int[].

In short, there are a lot of array int mixups to be fixed.

Comment: Where exactly do I attempt to assign it the value of an int? 
Should I use int or int[]? If I use int[], how can I proceed with division?
Sorry if this seems dumb, I'm really new to this and just trying too figure it out.

Comment: Your code has so many errors I can't begin to decipher its purpose. Use an int[] if you need an array of ints. Use an int if you need just one int. Whatever you use use it correctly. I'm not a mind reader.

Answer (score 0):

> > The issue is with the line int[] landkennung = serienNummer[0] - 'A' + 1;
>
> You declare landkennung as an int[], but attempt to assign it the
>   value of an int.

Another issue is you are using array as an integer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Pruefziffer {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Geben Sie die Seriennummer ein");
            int serienNummer = scanner.nextInt();

            int[] landkennung = new int[10];// Here you try to assign a int 
// where it is an array 
            landkennung[0] =serienNummer - 'A' + 1;
            int quersumme = (landkennung[0] % 10) + (landkennung[0] / 10);// // Here you try to acces array as an integer like `landkennung`
            int pruefziffer = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                quersumme += serienNummer - '0';

            }

            pruefziffer = 8 - quersumme % 9;

            if (pruefziffer == 0) {
                pruefziffer = 9;
            }
            System.out.println(pruefziffer);
        }
    }
```

Here I resolve some basic issue and commented what i change.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the help!!
I'm still not sure what exactly I should change to what, I copied the code as you have corrected it and get the "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException" error. Is the fault then with my formula or still with the ints and arrays?

Comment: I think you enter some character value where ` int serienNummer = scanner.nextInt();` is for only integer value

Comment: But the scanner needs to be able to read such 'U1234567890', any suggestions on how I can fix this? I'm sorry for all the questions

Comment: Then you should use `String` type

Comment: I've changed the code but I'm now getting this error: operator type -undefined for string, char. Why am I getting this error? How can I fix it? I've edited your above code to how I have it now.

Comment: @CharmaineNNdolo - I (and others) have rejected [your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10286955) because it conflicts with the original intent of the answer posted. When Uit suggests using a `string`, they presumably don't mean just changing the type to `string`.

Comment: Ok!! Can you maybe suggest what they meant? I'm new to programming and I've tried everything I can possible think of, would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you try to use an integer as an array. The very first problem in your code is :

```
int serienNummer = scanner.nextInt();

            int[] landkennung = serienNummer[0] - 'A' + 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you haven't use scanner class correctly. you need to get integer argument array using below points in your program as describe below.

1) you need to use while loop like  `while(scanner.hasNextInt())` for taking multiple value of int from scanner.

2) You will get single int from scanner inside while loop so you need to normal int instead of array in your code.

```
int[] landkennung = serienNummer[0] - 'A' + 1;
```

instead of use

```
int landkennung = serienNummer - 'A' + 1;
```

Hope this will help you